# Simple android app always crashes

Tags: android

Im newbie at developing Android apps but even the simpliest app always crashes when I try to add click listener I tried to google my problem but with no success. I also tried to change API to different versions at new project screen. Im able to run Hello World app but when I try to add listener to my app then Im no longer able to run it. Here is my error log.

```
03-02 21:13:49.153  19700-19700/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 21:13:49.163    1598-1922/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.example.app
03-02 21:13:49.163    1598-1922/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.example.app v1 (1.0)
03-02 21:13:49.163    1598-1922/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: My Application 7
03-02 21:13:51.566  19729-19729/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gallery3d.GooglePhotoProvider
03-02 21:13:56.871  19959-19959/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gallery3d.GooglePhotoProvider
```

And here only piece of code where I changed something (I added button in design)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                btn.setText("Hi");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: To prevent too much of guessing: Which line is actually: `MainActivity.java:32` ?

Comment: 32th line is `btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment on the last answer, you do not import any R file.

You need to import it this way:
`import com.<package_name>.<app_name>.R;`

That will import the ids generated file available into your Java code and the Button id `button` will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line 32 of the file `MainActivity.java`. Sounds like you're trying to call a method on a `null` object.

For example, are you sure your layout `activity_main.xml` contains a `Button` with an id `R.id.button`?

Comment: I think so or is this syntax wrong? `android:id="@+id/button"`

Comment: Nope. Looks good. Can you post the line 32 of the `MainActivity.java`, please?

Comment: 32th line is `btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` but this is written in every tutorial

Comment: Then I'm afraid, the problem comes from your layout file. Can you post the object `Button` from your layout file, please?

Comment: `<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="New Button"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
android:layout_marginLeft="29dp" />`

Comment: I thought R.java is autogenerated whenever I build my application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either that `R.id.button` doesn't exist in your `activity_main.xml` layout, or that there is something `null` in this code:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
      .commit();
}
```

Try them both out *separately* and figure out which one isn't working. Go from there.

By the way, the NullPointerException occurs on line 32.

Comment: The code you posted working fine its added when I create project. Problem occurs when I try to add the listener.

Comment: @user1816019 What are your import statements?

Comment: `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;`